# Issues to access to a list in Pandas dataframe - RESOLVED

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am currently working with list in a dataframe defined as follow :

```
class DATA():
def __init__(self):
    self.BDD_EEC = pd.DataFrame([],columns = ['Nom','Nmbre Param','Param', 'Units','Fixe','Min Param', 'Max Param','Entry', 'Equation'])

    ## R+R/C
    n=0
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Nom'] = 'Re+R1/C1'
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Nombre Param'] = 3
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Param'] = ['Re','C1','R1']
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Units'] = ['Ohm','F','Ohm']
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Fixe'] = [0,0,0]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Min Param'] = [0,1e-10,0]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Max Param'] = [1000,1,1e10]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Equation'] = 'Re+(R1)/(1+1j*2*np.pi*f*R1*Q1)'

    #### R+R/Q
    n = 1
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Nom'] = 'Re+R1/Q1'
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Nombre Param'] = 4
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Param'] = ['Re','Q1', 'a1', 'R1']
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Units'] = ['Ohm','F.s^(a-1)','--','Ohm']
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Fixe'] = [0,0,0,0]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Min Param'] = [0.001, 1e-10, 0.001, 0.001]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Max Param'] = [200, 1, 1, 1e6]
    self.BDD_EEC.at[n,'Equation'] = 'Re+(R1)/(1+1j*2*np.pi*f*np.power(R1*Q1,a1))'
```

After creating the object 'mes_datas', I try to access to the list ['Param'] thanks to the name, it works well :

```
mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Param'][mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Nom'] == 'Re+R1/C1'][0]
Out[26]: ['Re', 'C1', 'R1']
```

but with the other name, I have this error :

```
mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Param'][mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Nom'] == 'Re+R1/Q1'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\cboissy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1032, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1039, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-1bad18a3e796>", line 1, in <module>
    mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Param'][mes_datas.BDD_EEC['Nom'] == 'Re+R1/Q1'][0]

  File "C:\Users\cboissy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 882, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)

  File "C:\Users\cboissy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 989, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)

  File "C:\Users\cboissy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 0
```

I am quite confuse... Does anyone can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're getting KeyError because the returning index is `1`, not `0`. You can use `.iat[0]` to get first result:

```py
print(mes_datas.BDD_EEC.loc[mes_datas.BDD_EEC["Nom"] == "Re+R1/Q1", "Param"].iat[0])
```

Prints:

```
['Re', 'Q1', 'a1', 'R1']
```